# Use flavor/buildTypes/productFlavors/variants for App Engine with Gradle?

Tags: google-app-engine, intellij-idea, gradle, android-studio, build.gradle

I want to be able to build both a dev/prod variant for an App Engine backend, namely because I want to exchange one file for the development server. So something like this (Pseudo Code):

```
flavors {
  dev
  prod extends dev   // uses folder 'prod' that overrides some files
}
```

Is there any way to do achieve this by using the default *appengine* plugin? I cannot find anything useful in the [App Engine Readme.](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/gradle-appengine-plugin/blob/master/README.md)

Thanks a lot for helping!

Comment: Unfortunately flavors is a feature of the android gradle plugin.  The appengine plugin doesn't natively support this.  You might be able to do this by including custom build logic in your build.gradle file that does this for you.

Comment: Just to build on what loosebazooka said you can do this: import os

 if os.environ['SERVER_SOFTWARE'].startswith('Development'): to check if your in dev, set a flag and work from there.